# LAN resets if I reboot router, but is there a better way to troubleshoot the LAN connection

Tags: networking, local-area-network, netgear

Ok,
  I have the typical problem of intermittent internet drops on my home network.  To restore the internet, I simply have to cycle power on the router.  Problem solved.

But I don't understand why the router stops communicating.  I'd like to have a better troubleshooting technique and eliminate the drops, but I don't know where to look.  Here's what I've tried:

I have a script that pings the router from a connected LAN computer on a regular schedule and I have been tracking the drop times for 3 weeks.  There is no pattern in the times that I notice -- except of course it's always happening when my wife wants to connect...FYI. its on an almost daily basis.

My ISP gives IP leases on a 24 hour basis, but the router is set to renew connections and I have had the router up for a stretch of 4 days without a failure.

My router is a Netgear WGR614 v6, and the only logs it keeps are content logs--which get erased every time I cycle power so I have no idea what they said when the router stopped.

When the router stops, 
a) it still has power
b) the lights indicate it is still communicating with the cable modem.  But I cannot confirm since I can't see any of the traffic.
c) It will not acknowledge (via ping) wired or wireless computers on the LAN, even a computer that has a static IP and wired into the router.
d) No connectivity (especially internet...) for any computer on the LAN.

My LAN topology is 
Cable Modem -> Router -> local computers.

Cheers,
--Jim Parker

Comment: Ok, I agree this is an end-user issue.  Do you have a recommendation for an alternate forum?

Answer (score 1):

Most SOHO routers have problems with overheating or poor power supply. Both can end in such problem.

If you want to investigate it from software side: please forward logs from your router to external syslog server.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I don't have an "external syslog server" that I know of. The router only has content logs and they are not accessible once the router fails.  Is there some logging function I can enable on the router to generate this information?

Answer (score 0):

With consumer routers, I've personally never found any rhyme or reason that they go out, the interfaces are often very limited compared to a professional grade piece of equipment, so there isn't really much that can be done. You're already checking the logs and looking to see if there's a timing pattern...

Perhaps use  wireshark to investigate traffic, if you are familiar with packet inspection? Maybe you can find a pattern there.

Comment: Ok.  I'll set up wireshark and let it run for a few days.  Will post the results here, once complete.